# Regular expresion to catch file name and replace it with specific characters

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I need help in a specific problem.

I have a relative Path in a Flutter project, and I need to get the file name (without .dart extension) and adding two asterisks before that.

I need to create a shell script to execute in my PC like this:

EJ.

- Convert this

```
prueba/de/una/ruta/main.dart
```

- Into this

```
prueba/de/una/ruta/**.dart
```

----

Actually I'm trying something like get the file name and replace it with this code but is not working

```
echo "test/holas.dart" | sed "/(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\.dart)/g";
```

Actual output:

```
test/holas.dart
```

Expected output:

```
holas
```

If someone know something to get the expected output or how to build the entire Script file i appreciate help

Comment: Without the `-E` option, `sed` only uses "basic" regular expressions ("BRE"), which are extremely limited. With `-E`, it uses "extended" regular expressions ("ERE"), which are actually still somewhat limited -- in particular, they don't support lookahead/behind assertions like the ones you're using. See [this table](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html) for a good summary of several different flavors of regex syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo 'prueba/de/una/ruta/main.dart' | sed -E 's~(.*/)[^.]*~\1**~'
prueba/de/una/ruta/**.dart
```

```
$ echo "test/holas.dart" | sed -E 's~.*/|\..*~~g'
holas
```

Comment: I need to add into a Makefile this command you gave me, but it doesn’t work there, any idea ? This is the Makefile option.

`
autogf:
 @bash -c 'echo ;\
 echo EJ. flutter pub run build_runner build --build-filter "lib/auth/core/domain/main.dart"; \
 read -p "[Path to file] " path; \
  echo flutter pub run build_runner build --build-filter $$path | sed "s/^\(.\{1,\}\/\).*\([.]dart\)$/\1**\2/"; \
 echo ;\
 '
`

Comment: @HadjukSanchez: Don't put complete code into a comment, as it is hard to read. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.